# Android RatingBar Style Small showing error in Android studio

Tags: android

I am using RatingBar in android and want to reduce the size of it , so I added

> style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"

as Ratting Bar Style attribute. It is working fine but it is showing error in code

[image]

below is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion " 22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':vitamio')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    }
```

Please help what I am doing wrong..

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: put the error log

Comment: @JinalPatel Not getting any error. just it is showing the attribute value in red. As shown in image

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
add this to ur gradle

Comment: @JinalPatel I can't update my dependency version

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead `style="?attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

Comment: @Pallavi what's the problem?

Comment: @Pallavi  can you post your full `styles.xml`?